# Optimize retrieval of screenshots in Windows service (C#)

Tags: c#, .net, windows, performance, service

I am building an application to periodically perform image recognition in screenshots, using C# and .NET Framework 4.8. The app runs as a Windows 10 service (S) and therefore can't take screenshots of the user session.

For this and for several other reasons, I automatically run another, small process (P) in each logged in user's session. My service can communicate with it using a Semaphore and a memory mapped file (details omitted, this works well).

My problem is: Taking the screenshot in P, copying it to the memory mapped file in P, retrieving the copy in S and unpacking the image in S is **simply not fast enough**. I am talking about 1-2s each run, but my service needs to have the screenshot **about every 600ms** or even faster. Code snippets are below.

What would you propose to make the workflow faster? I've tried real files on the disk before, which was even slower. My idea would be to only hand over the device context from P to S, but I have concerns for the stability of this. At the end of the day I need the image as [EmguCV Mat](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/files/3.1.0/document/html/2ec33afb-1d2b-cac1-ea60-0b4775e4574c.htm) in the service. Currently, I save the screenshot to the MMF as PNG to save memory, but this doesn't help much.

My code to get the screenshot in the process looks like this:

```cs
private static readonly object memoryLock = new object();
public void TakeScreenshots(ref MemoryMappedViewStream screenshotMemoryStream)
{
    lock (memoryLock)
    {
        using (var screenCaptureBitmap = new Bitmap(SystemInformation.VirtualScreen.Width, SystemInformation.VirtualScreen.Height, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb))
        using (var captureWrapper = Graphics.FromImage(screenCaptureBitmap))
        {
            screenshotMemoryStream.Position = 0;
            captureWrapper.CopyFromScreen(SystemInformation.VirtualScreen.Left, SystemInformation.VirtualScreen.Top, 0, 0, SystemInformation.VirtualScreen.Size);
            screenCaptureBitmap.Save(screenshotMemoryStream, ImageFormat.Png);
            screenshotMemoryStream.Flush();
        }
    }
}
```

Receiving it on the other end using

```cs
screenshotMemoryStream.Position = 0;
var screenshot = new Bitmap(screenshotMemoryStream).ToImage<Rgba, byte>();
```

I am making sure everything is disposed properly, so please overlook my handling of the memory streams.

Comment: png is non-trivial to encode/decode - have you tried it with bmp? (would need more memory, but you could compress in a background thread in the service).

Comment: Wow, that greatly decreses the runtime, it's okay with the "raw" bitmap. Didn't think it would affect my performance that bad. Thanks a lot!

Comment: If the limitation is the saving of the image to disk, you could always do that step on another, or even multiple threads.

Comment: Well, unfortunately no: I need the screenshot immediately after requesting it for further processing. It doesn't need to be saved to the disk, because I don't care for the screenshots once it's processed, but saving it to file instead of to RAM in order to get it from P to S was not fast enough.